# Trying to run rubymine but getting error no JDK found

Tags: ruby, jdk

Getting the following:

```
ERROR: cannot start RubyMine.
No JDK found.
```

How can I fix this so that rubyMine starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this answer at StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891.

Instructions for RubyMine would be the same, the only difference is the startup script, use `bin/rubymine.sh` instead of `bin/idea.sh`.